# Recursive function that returns a bool?

Tags: c++

I want to make a recursive function that iterates through a tree and the first time the condition hits, I want it to return. Would this be proper?

```
bool nodeExists(Node *root, Node *target)
{
    if(root == target)
    {
        return true;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < root->nodes.size(); ++i)
    {            
        if(nodeExists(root->nodes[i],target)) {return true;}    
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Does it test okay?  If it fails tests, then It Does Not Work.  If it passes tests, and you still have concerns about it, then you should describe your tests and articulate your concerns.

Comment: -1: As comments suggest, you should have just tested it yourself and asked if something specific does not work.

Comment: You should indent your code consistently, but there's absolutely nothing wrong with multiple returns from a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's good, but I'd rather use a different identifier than "nodes". "children" is nice because it's clear and unambiguous.

Comment: Yea I just used node to be generic, I actually use children and iterators

Answer (score 1):

I think you wrote it properly. Did you test it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks good. Though you should really test your code, maybe you have any errors with pointers. (Depends on your Node class very much...)

Answer (score 0):

That would work, since the return statement automatically exits the function. Another way would be:

```
bool nodeExists(Node *root, Node *target)
{
    if(root == target)
    {
        return true;
    }

    bool returnValue = false; 

    for(int i = 0; i < root->nodes.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(nodeExists(root->nodes[i],target)) {returnValue = true; break;}
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: This, however, is more complicated and gains nothing.

Comment: I didn't say it was a better way, just an alternative. This is practically equivalent to the original. Breaking up a function into smaller parts makes it easier to understand what is actually going on.

Comment: @Evan: No, no it doesn't. A function should always return as soon as possible. The OP's original code is vastly easier to understand than your posted code.

Comment: It still returns as soon as possible. Also, if the OP needed to do further evaluation (i.e. another iteration), this would be the ideal way.

Comment: @DeadMG: Exiting as quickly as possible is not always an option. For instance, if you were coding to MISRA standards, having multiple return statements in a function is not allowed; and, of course, neither are `goto` s or `break`. So you end up using a lot of boolean checks and writing code similar to what Evan posted, excepted you'd set a boolean and check it in the `for` loop's exit condition to break out of the loop. The code looks ugly, and IMO is less readable, but according to MISRA all that clutter makes it less error prone :-)

Comment: @Evan: "It still returns as soon as possible." No it doesn't, it stores the intended return value in a variable, breaks from a loop, then returns the value of that variable. That's a pretty long way of doing `return true;`. @Prae: That's a pretty awful argument you've got there. "But what if we had insert-random-restriction?" Then random-restriction takes precedence. So what?

Comment: @GMan: I wasn't trying to suggest Evan's method is better or worse; just that absolute statements such as "A function should always return as soon as possible" are not always achievable given other constraints. Also, I'm not a fan of MISRA guidelines but am forced to follow that for some projects.

Comment: I don't think the additional time required to perform the task of setting the `returnValue` is significant, especially with today's processors. And, as I previously stated, if the OP needed to do further evaluation (i.e. another iteration), multiple boolean checks are an ideal way, and, as stated by @Praetorian, are less error prone.

Comment: @Evan: I was trying to point out the irony behind the reasoning of those particular set of guidelines that adding a bunch of boolean checks is supposed to make the code less error prone. I personally feel returning as quickly as possible from a function is the best implementation and makes the code a lot more readable.

Comment: @Prae: My response is independent of Evan's answer, I didn't suggest you tried to suggest his method was better or worse. Rather, absolute statements are fine within their domain. @Dead made a perfectly acceptable and agreeable absolute statement. When *you* change the domain of which we're working with to some other arbitrary domain, that's fine, but don't except other statements made in a more general domain to hold and then say "nu-uh". Or for any statement you make I can say "well what about theoretical universe X where that doesn't hold! You cannot make absolute claims ever."

Comment: @Evan: ...? Nobody said anything about running time. Where did you pull that from? And you're doing the same thing as Praetorian: okay, there could be some other theoretical constraints or goals; so what? As it is, he *doesn't*, so what purpose is there mentioning it? Would you give an answer in Java and justify it with "he might eventually program in Java!"? I'd hope not. So why support an argument with a random unnecessary framework?

Comment: @GMan: Your comment "That's a pretty long way...". And the fact that the OP stated he *simplified* his posted code by using Node instead of children and iterators implies that he may alter his code at some point.

Comment: @GMan: Agreed, maybe I was a little too happy to point out a case where that statement doesn't apply.

Comment: @Evan: Long as in program flow. That is, `return true;` is the absolute shortest way of returning true in standard C++, while `bool b = false; b = true; return b;` is not. And yes, I never said it *won't ever change*; but I did say there's no reason to assume it will, and then support an answer with it. Please note there's a difference between "X will not happen" and "We don't know X will happen."

Comment: @GMan: I completely agree that `return true;` is ultimately the "shortest route," if you will, but in essence, both the OP's original code and mine are correct. There isn't only one way to do something.

Comment: @Evan: ...sigh. Please read what I'm writing and stop putting words in my mouth. Where did I say "there is only one way to do something"? Hm? Where did I say your code was wrong? I don't see it, help me out here.

Comment: @GMan: I wasn't trying to, just stating a fact. My apologies.